# Why am I not able to fetch my data using an axios call?

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const EMPLOYEE_API_BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/employees";

class EmployeeService {

    getEmployees(){
        return axios.get(EMPLOYEE_API_BASE_URL);
    }
}
const obj = new EmployeeService()
export default obj
```

I am expecting to get my data in my React app, which is not been fetched by my React.

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
const getEmployee = getEmployees()
getEmployee
   .then(res => console.log("response", res))
   .catch(e => console.log("error", e))
```